# Gradle sync error in android

Tags: android

I am getting this kind of error.

> Gradle sync failed: Operation timed out. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.
>               Consult IDE log for more details

what can I try?

Comment: run `./gradlew --info build` from command line at the root directory of the project and paste the output here.

Comment: there is problem with network now its working fine @Yashasvi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It seems like the IDE is not able to connect to internet, could you please make sure it is.
2. go to File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System settings >HTTP Proxy and check if proxy setting is proper, if you don't need proxy to connect to internet then select Auto detect proxy setting then click "check connection" button check if its successful. and clean project and rebuild
   hope it works